# PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Уже переломал голову. В логах указывается на 97 строку.

Она есть: `$vkAPI = new \BW\Vkontakte("access_token" => $accessToken);`

Пробовал так `$vkAPI = new BW Vkontakte("access_token" => $accessToken);`

И так `$vkAPI = new BW Vkontakte("access_token" => "$accessToken");`

И еще кучу вариантов с кавычками и пр. В саблайме синтаксис подсвечивается нормально. Так и не дошёл умом, почему РНР ругается на эту строку.

Если может помочь:

1. Используется этот класс https://github.com/Vastly/vkontakte-php-sdk
2. Собственно перед вызовом класса есть всего 3 строки - с токеном, идом приложения, и текстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new \BW\Vkontakte(['access_token' => $accessToken]);
```

или

```
new \BW\Vkontakte(array('access_token' => $accessToken));
```

Comment: @zhenyab При варианте первом: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' ` если заменить квадратные скобки на круглые, то дубль того, что ниже. 

При варианте втором: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW`

Comment: array же нужно указать, если версия PHP не поддерживает квадратные скобки

Comment: < 5.4 - `array()`
>= 5.4 - `[]` или `array()`